# Relation between Dictionary's Key Hashcode and index of bucket where value is storing

Tags: c#

Wiki says (as I understand it) that every time when I'm adding an item to the dictionary, the system calculates hash code (by calling GetHashCode). The system then using the hash code to find a bucket where my value will be saved.

Explain me please the logic of finding relation between hash code and index in the bucket array where my value will be stored by a Dictionary.

Imagine situation when I creating a Dictiornary and adding an object to it who's GetHashCode returns value 1000000.

Does it mean that inside Dictionary will create an Array with 1000000 elements and store my object at index 999999999 ?

If that's assumption is correct, what's the point of having array of such a big size to store only one value.

Comment: The relationship is not documented, an update to the CLI could change it. Various tools allow for the decompilation of assemblies so you could work it out. But, any dependency on the specifics is potential for random breakage. As this sounds like an XY Problem: why do you want to know?

Comment: No the index will be calculated from the combination of the hash code and table size (e.g. `hashCode % table.Count`) and the result of resolving any collisions. You can see the implementation [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9)

Comment: Conceptually, a hash bucket *could* be merely a reference point indicating where values of a given index or index range could be stored. It doesn't necessarily have to map to direct physical storage. It could also be implemented an "array of locations" - if an implementation provided a default of, say, 10 buckets, each bucket could be nothing more than a linked list if key/value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption isn't correct, luckily. If it were, they wouldn't actually be *buckets*, just an index-accessible array of objects. That might be fine for O(1) lookup if your hashcodes are guaranteed to be unique, but that's not the case - in fact, hashcodes are guaranteed *not* to be unique. You can't map every possible value of an Int64 into a unique Int32 hashcode. That's not what hashcodes are for.

Instead, the dictionary initializes a smaller array of buckets, and then uses a simple Modulo operation to find the bucket. (From the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,327))

```
 int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
```

That means that if there are 10 buckets, for instance, it will get the remainder of dividing the hashcode by 10. If your hash algorithm does its job well, it means that the hashcodes follow a standard distribution, meaning that any *n* items, for a big enough *n*, will probably be evenly divided between the buckets.

As for how many buckets are initialized, the number will be the first prime number that's higher than the capacity passed in the ctor, or 0 ([See here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,1717)). If this causes too many hash collisions, it will be automatically expanded, jumping to the next prime number each time, until stable.